# Easier way to pass data around a web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I suspect that I'm making life harder for myself, but is there an easier way to pass data around a given page?

For example say I have a table with a button, and with that button I call a modal that has form information.  The modal form may also have a button that could call another type of form.

I shouldn't have to constantly pass data from the main table to each modal should I?

Basically on each button click I'm adding a "data-value" attribute to it and reading that JSON object in a given modal.  This seems like a lot of unnecessary work. Could I possibly be missing some JQuery techniques to get the data from the clicked table row (instead of passing the JSON object to each modal)?

EDIT:
The page loads a table.
I dynamically create the rows and on the rows are buttons.

```
<table id='main'>
<tr><td>Joe</td><td><button type='button' class='editPerson' data-value='personObject' /></td></tr>
<table>
```

Now button 'editPerson' calls bootstrap modal.  In Jquery I populate the modal form with the personObject.

In this modal there is a

```
<button type='button' id='addFeature' data-value='personObject' />
```

I call a second modal once again passing the personObject to it.

Is this the right approach or can I simply just reference the (editPerson) button click and pull its value?

Comment: Could you show an example of what you're currently doing?

Comment: You could create an object array containing the information, and just push new objects to it

Comment: Added a pseudo example in edit.

Comment: With a better idea of what your script looks like we might be able to offer a JavaScript or local storage solution. As it is, your question is unclear.